# how to write a web services for my asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have an asp.net mvc3 website, I need to update the database periodically, for example, get some web resources from another site and use that as my data. I think I should write some web services to do the job since the service should be running all the time, but I don't know where to start, is this hard? Where can I find the right tutorials for this job..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to update the *data* periodically, here are some questions you need to consider:

- Will the data updates be driven by user input? If so, the web application will update the data, there are numerous ways this can be accomplished, I assume you have some sort of method established to communicate with your data store?
- Will the data be updated by another data source? If so, consider using SSIS or some other ETL tool, if the data can be "batched", i.e. loaded nightly or hourly
- Thirdly, I'm not sure what your scenario is, from the question its pretty broad, you could use a Windows Service as an option if you are more comfortable populating your data via C#/VB.NET as opposed to something like SSIS. The Windows Service can periodically perform an action on your behalf.

Finally, maybe update your question a bit, "update database periodically" is very vague.

Comment: periodically means once a week, and I need to get the information from other website api to use in my site.